# How to get value which is used for div visible condition in c# selenium

Tags: c#, html, knockout.js, selenium-chromedriver, observable

```
    <div data-bind="css: resultClass, visible: model.ticketId() !== ''" id="result">
-------------
</div>
```

One of my html form page has div visible based on condition like above and it was using knockoutjs.
Now i am doing automate testing using selenium webdriver.
It was getback with valid TicketId value with successful submission, so here i want to get that model.ticketId() value with selenium c#.
if that model.TicketId() displays like this `'<span data-bind="mode.ticketId()"></span'>` i can able to get element text using FindElement.
But in the above scenario i could not able to get value of model.ticketId() value.
Please help me anybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some form of `ko.dataFor(document.getElementById('elementId'))` and `ko.contextFor(document.getElementById('elementId'))` to get the data and context for a given DOM element.  Replace the `document.getElementById` with how you are retrieving Dom elements.  I use `ko.dataFor($0)` in the browser console a lot to get the data for the currently selected DOM element when using the browser inspect element functionality.